# View Contextual Filter with external Database - Drupal 7

Tags: views, database

I've created a custom module to display in views an external database.
Everything is working fine and the data are displayed right.

The problem start when I want to use contextual filter.

-I create a views block to pull data from my external database

-I add a new Contextual filter picking up the field which I want to filter (in my case "city").

- First I get this message: *"city
  This display does not have a source for contextual filters, so no contextual filter value will be available unless you select 'Provide default'."*
- I select "taxonomy term Id from Url", I checked *"Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks"*
- I checked my vocabulary which contain the terms.

If I try in "preview with contextual filter" to query with "Rome" (for example) I get all the record with Rome.

But when I attach this view block with a node wich has a taxonomy term "Rome" the record doesn't get filtered.

I've also tried "Raw value from url" to get the term from the url. Also in this way doesn't work.

When I make the same operation above using instead of external database some drupal nodes everything is working fine.

I guess the problem could be because the external database cannot comunicate with a drupal database at the same time.
Maybe there is some php code to use to solve the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you establish a relationship between the two databases on the taxonomy term?

Comment: If I add relationship I get an empty window saying this message _There are no relationships available to add._
This is happening only with views calling an external database.
If views instead is managing only drupal database the relationship windows has a list of field to select.